# logic to define arrival time greater than 30 minutes of scheduled appointment window end time : Oracle

Tags: oracle, datetime

Oracle SQL developer:
I have 2 fields in question -

Arrival time : Date time format  (example: 01-JAN-15 11:03:00)
Service window End time: HH:MM (Varchar)  ( example: 20:00)

I have to apply the logic where Arrival time is 30 minutes or more after service window end time.

Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your `arrival_time` as `date`, we can use following logic.

```
Select * from your_table
Where (to_date(
         to_char(arrival_time,'dd-mon-yyyy') 
         || ' ' 
         ||service_window_end_time
      ,'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi') - arrival_time)*24*60 > 30 
  -- difference of dates give the number of days 
  -- so converted it to number of minutes by multiplying it with 24*60
```

But please note that your logic will not work when `arrival_time` and `service_window_end_time` represents different days.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you Tejash, this was very helpful. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `INTERVAL` to add minutes.

```
SELECT SYSDATE schedule_end_time, 
       SYSDATE + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE arrival_time
FROM dual
```

You can then use this in the `WHERE` clause with a greater than operator to do the comparison.

Comment: Thank you, this is not accurate on what i want but It gave me an idea on how to add minutes